# Certificate check fails with Python requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I'm attempting to load a website using the [Python requests package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) via a http/https proxy:

```
url = 'https://booster-magazine.ch'  # Example of failing URL
proxies = {
    'http': 'proxy.domain.internal:4321',
    'https': 'proxy.domain.internal:4321',
}
r = requests.get(url, proxies=proxies)
```

Running this triggers the following error message
`requests.exceptions.SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL Routine', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)`

Web browsers indicate that the site's certificate is trusted and cURL on the command line using the same webproxy as the python code works just fine.

```
curl -x proxy.domain.internal:4321 https://booster-magazine.ch  # No error
```

Some sites I have tested fail, while others work fine. As far as I can tell, the [SSL Labs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=booster-magazine.ch) for this failing site doesn't have any issues.

Package versions I'm using:

```
requests==2.23.0
certifi==2020.4.5.1
```

I'm aware of the existence of the `verify=False` option in the requests library. This is generally bad practice and opens the possibility to mitm attacks. The goal is to have a working ssl validation.

Comment: remove the "https" key-value and re-run the app. I suppose it should run fine because `requests` is a http library

Comment: try with `verify=False` in your requests.get

Comment: @bigbounty without an https proxy it's not even possible to establish a connection to the https server, so this would be a step backwards

Comment: @MohitC the whole point of fixing this issue is to ensure the ssl verification is done and have its security benefits. I will update the question to clarify

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this after trying without proxies, and if SSL Labs report says its all fine, problem has to be in your setup. When I try without proxies it gives me error `requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname 'booster-magazine.ch' doesn't match either of '*.hoststar.hosting', 'hoststar.hosting'`

Comment: Try `http://proxy.domain.internal:4321` as your proxy.

Comment: looking at my error, to me it looks like your requests is picking up certificate of another server

Comment: You could also try `pip install requests[security]` which installs requests with security modules

Comment: @MohitC Accessing without a proxy should work (already tested, but from a different machine). There are two certificates on the domain and the first one is valid for the given hostname. The requests[security] package is already installed. The issue may very well be the proxy, but I don't know (yet) how to find why the certificate validation fails, and the setup works fine with other sites.

Comment: Clearly your target site has a good cert. Therefore the cert that’s failing validation is the proxy. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/133254/how-does-ssl-proxy-server-in-company-work

Comment: @barny I also believe the proxy plays a role. However, cURL successfully validates the ssl certificate, which suggests the proxy is clear. Uncovering the reason why it fails with requests seems to me the required step to be able to fix the issue (whether it lies in the proxy or elsewhere).

Comment: Please check the certificate chain you get with `openssl s_client -proxy proxy.domain.internal:4321 -connect booster-magazine.ch:443` and compare it to the one you see in the SSLLabs report. My guess is that there is some SSL intercepting proxy (common in companies) and that the CA from this proxy is trusted by some applications (browser, curl) but not all. Python requests uses a different trust store than curl or the browsers so this might explain different behavior.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion? "Try `http://proxy.domain.internal:4321` as your proxy." You actually need the protocol part.

Comment: I’ve had some struggles using requests with Telerik Fiddler acting as a proxy for https, to get requests to use the proxy. Do you know anythng about your proxy server? If you access a site through this proxy, with its ‘trusted’ cert, look at it in more detail, who signed/is in the trust chain for that cert?

Comment: Hi @Sraw sorry I forgot to reply. I did, but specifying the protocol (with http or https) didn't have any impact

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have tried this (had to build a more recent openssl to get the proxy option). It turns out the issue is most certainly due to requests not being able to validate the ssl certificate given by the proxy

Comment: @barny your hunch was right, the proxy certificate was not trusted by requests due to missing CA cert. I'm now left wondering why it worked with some sites, but at least the setup is now fixed.

Comment: @Ire: A proxy might choose to SSL intercept some sites but not others. The check with `s_client` should reveal if the site is intercepted by the proxy or not.